# Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.NullHandler' in Django 1.9+

Tags: python, django

After upgrading to Django 1.9 or 1.10, LOGGING configurations with django.utils.log.NullHandler throws an exception saying that the NullHandler is not resolvable:

```
Unable to configure handler 'null': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.NullHandler': No module named NullHandler
```

This can also happen if copy/pasting commonly suggested log configurations into new projects based upon Django 1.9 or 1.10.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I found this question very useful.

Comment: I also find this question very useful

Answer (score 71):

`django.utils.log.NullHandler` is actually alias to `logging.NullHandler`.

Looks like it was removed in 1.9.

Just check your settings (and any other code) and replace `django.utils.log.NullHandler` with `logging.NullHandler`.

Comment: i just add the code in django loging and the error was solved.. but i got another error django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty when the secret_key already declare in my settings.py

Comment: Oh no, why do you edit library code? You are on a wrong way. If you have SECRET_KEY isn your settings file, but got this eror, it looks like your settings are not used. Check DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable

Comment: because i found the solution to add the code in here 

http://django-compositekey.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/django/utils/log.html